# How to use variables from one class in another class

Tags: python

I know this question has been asked before but for the life of me I can't seem to understand the answers so I'm here asking for some help with an example. I am not trying to waste anybodies time here so please don't internet yell at me!

I have a class called Enemy with variables. How do I access these variables in another class?
Heres my example.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk

class Enemy(object):
def __init__ (self, name, attack, defence, gold, health, experience):

    self.name = name
    self.attack = attack
    self.defence = defence
    self.gold = gold
    self.health = health
    self.experience = experience

    Enemy1 = Enemy("Enemy Soldier", "5", "1", "10", "10", "30")

class Application(object):

def __init__(self):

    self.enemyLabel = tkinter.Label(text= self.Enemy1.name)
    self.enemyLabel.pack()     

myApp = Application()
myApp.root.mainloop()
```

This is a very narrowed down version of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define `enemy1` in the scope of `Application.__init__`:

```
class Enemy(object):
    def init (self, name, attack, defence, gold, health, experience):
        self.name = name
        self.attack = attack
        self.defence = defence
        self.gold = gold
        self.health = health
        self.experience = experience

class Application(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.enemy1 = Enemy("Enemy Soldier", "5", "1", "10", "10", "30")
        self.enemyLabel = tkinter.Label(text=self.enemy1.name)
        self.enemyLabel.pack()
```

Answer (score 0):

Anywhere within the scope of where you created `Enemy1`, you can simply use `Enemy1.name`, `Enemy1.attack`, etc.